# Сложить элементы массива до определенного значения

Tags: php

Нужно сложить элементы массива `$tovar` до того, пока они не достигнут значения количества денег в массиве `$pokupatel`, и вывести товары, которые добавились.

Массивы:

```
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>26500,"Name"=>"Козлов Михаил Иванович");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>31000,"Name"=>"Поттер Гарри Озборн");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>12000,"Name"=>"Иванова Галина Петровна");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>27000,"Name"=>"Бондарчук Виктор Васильевич");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>3000,"Name"=>"Сёмкин Дмитрий Андреевич");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>9000,"Name"=>"Маленко Светлана Анатольевна");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>8999,"NameTov"=>"Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>3599,"NameTov"=>"Телефон Nokia Lumia 730");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1999,"NameTov"=>"mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>5199,"NameTov"=>"Монитор Dell 27PR9465IT");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1999,"NameTov"=>"Телефон ACER Liquid Z5");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>8799,"NameTov"=>"Ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad T6395");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>4399,"NameTov"=>"Планшет ASUS Transformer Book T8569");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>699,"NameTov"=>"Клавиатура A4Tech KV-300H");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1599,"NameTov"=>"Бритва Braun R439");
```

Comment: @АндрейБатарон,  Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: $tovar... Dengi... Cena...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
перебирать $pokupatel
обнулить массив покупок
 перебирать $tovar 
  Cena вычитать из Dengi, 
  если Dengi - <0 остановиться, 
   иначе - записать в Dengi новое значение; добавить в выходной массив текущее значение массива $tovar.
 вывести массив покупок
выйти
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>26500,"Name"=>"Козлов Михаил Иванович");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>31000,"Name"=>"Поттер Гарри Озборн");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>12000,"Name"=>"Иванова Галина Петровна");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>27000,"Name"=>"Бондарчук Виктор Васильевич");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>3000,"Name"=>"Сёмкин Дмитрий Андреевич");
$pokupatel[]=array("Dengi"=>9000,"Name"=>"Маленко Светлана Анатольевна");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>8999,"NameTov"=>"Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>3599,"NameTov"=>"Телефон Nokia Lumia 730");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1999,"NameTov"=>"mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>5199,"NameTov"=>"Монитор Dell 27PR9465IT");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1999,"NameTov"=>"Телефон ACER Liquid Z5");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>8799,"NameTov"=>"Ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad T6395");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>4399,"NameTov"=>"Планшет ASUS Transformer Book T8569");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>699,"NameTov"=>"Клавиатура A4Tech KV-300H");
$tovar[]=array("Cena"=>1599,"NameTov"=>"Бритва Braun R439");

function show_client($client, $comment){
    printf("<br>&emsp;%s %s %d<br>", $client["Name"], $comment, $client["Dengi"]);
}

function show_tovar($tovar){
    print("<br>tovar ="); print_r($tovar);
}

function korzina($item, $key, array &$client){
    global $client;
    if($client["Dengi"] >= $item["Cena"]){
        show_tovar($item);
        $client["Dengi"] -= $item["Cena"];
        array_push($client["Korzina"], $item);
    }
}

function tovar($item, $key){
    global $service, $client, $tovar;
    $client = $item; 
    $client["Korzina"] = array();
    show_client($client, ". При себе денег: ");
    array_walk($tovar,'korzina',$client);
    show_client($client, ". Осталось денег: ");
    array_push($service, $client);
}

$service = array();
array_walk($pokupatel, 'tovar');
```

С таким результатом:

```
 Козлов Михаил Иванович . При себе денег: 26500

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8999 [NameTov] => Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 3599 [NameTov] => Телефон Nokia Lumia 730 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 5199 [NameTov] => Монитор Dell 27PR9465IT ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => Телефон ACER Liquid Z5 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 4399 [NameTov] => Планшет ASUS Transformer Book T8569 ) 
 Козлов Михаил Иванович . Осталось денег: 306

 Поттер Гарри Озборн . При себе денег: 31000

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8999 [NameTov] => Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 3599 [NameTov] => Телефон Nokia Lumia 730 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 5199 [NameTov] => Монитор Dell 27PR9465IT ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => Телефон ACER Liquid Z5 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8799 [NameTov] => Ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad T6395 ) 
 Поттер Гарри Озборн . Осталось денег: 406

 Иванова Галина Петровна . При себе денег: 12000

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8999 [NameTov] => Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 699 [NameTov] => Клавиатура A4Tech KV-300H ) 
 Иванова Галина Петровна . Осталось денег: 303

 Бондарчук Виктор Васильевич . При себе денег: 27000

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8999 [NameTov] => Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 3599 [NameTov] => Телефон Nokia Lumia 730 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 5199 [NameTov] => Монитор Dell 27PR9465IT ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => Телефон ACER Liquid Z5 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 4399 [NameTov] => Планшет ASUS Transformer Book T8569 ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 699 [NameTov] => Клавиатура A4Tech KV-300H ) 
 Бондарчук Виктор Васильевич . Осталось денег: 107

 Сёмкин Дмитрий Андреевич . При себе денег: 3000

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 1999 [NameTov] => mp3 плеер Apple iPod Shuffle 4Gb ) 
tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 699 [NameTov] => Клавиатура A4Tech KV-300H ) 
 Сёмкин Дмитрий Андреевич . Осталось денег: 302

 Маленко Светлана Анатольевна . При себе денег: 9000

tovar = Array ( [Cena] => 8999 [NameTov] => Телевизор Toshiba 42FJ8775 ) 
 Маленко Светлана Анатольевна . Осталось денег: 1
```